# Placing UILabel along drawn line

Tags: ios, swift, math

I want to place UILabel along drawn line with CAShapeLayer.

Like that:

[image]

Currently I can't understand how to calculate X and Y points to place the label at center of the line taking into calculated angle.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let linePath = UIBezierPath()

    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: initialPoint.x, y: initialPoint.y))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: finalPoint.x, y: finalPoint.y))

    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    lineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    lineLayer.lineCap = .round
    lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath

    view.layer.insertSublayer(lineLayer, at: 0)

    // X & Y don't place correctly
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (initialPoint.x - finalPoint.x) / 2, y: (initialPoint.y - finalPoint.y) / 2, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))

    let angle = atan2(finalPoint.x - initialPoint.x, finalPoint.y - initialPoint.y + navigationHeight)

    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = label.font.withSize(24.0)
    label.text = "Text here"

    label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)

    view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to place the label between `initialPoint ` and `finalPoint `? If so, you may have missed adding `initialPoint.x` and `initialPoint.y` when computing the frame. The way you've written the code, you just simply compute the half of the distance between initial point and final point, and put your label at that coordinates.

Comment: Also, if you want to center the label on the line, it would be easier to use `label.center = CGPoint(...)` instead of frame. The frame places the top left corner at the given coordinates, whereas the center places the view's center. It will make the calculations easier.

Comment: The midpoint is calculated as `(Start + End) / 2`. The midpoint should be at the bottom center of your label. If you are rotating the label, don't even bother to calculate frame. Calculate only `.bounds` (that is, label size) and label `.center`.